# PHP: Handle the ' and " in file handling and SQL

Tags: php, sql, database, file-handling

I have a file that contains both single quote(') and double quote("). There is a field in database where i am saving the content of the file.

Now, the problem arises in the SQL query as ' and " conflicts with each other. There is ' quote in SQL query and file content has their own. So, they are conflicting. How can i handle this?

Here is the code which i am trying to do:

```
$filename = "folder/file.txt";
$file_content = file_get_contents($filename);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table (content)
        VALUES ('.$file_content.')';
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "value submitted";
}else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the string before inserting with the help of `mysql_real_escape_string` method.

Comment: Welcome, please accept the answer and upvote if it is useful.